# Compiling python file with clang and build.ll file

Tags: python, clang, llvm

Does anyone know if there is a way to compile a python file with clang and produce .ll file?

Comment: Have you looked at `cpython` compilers? I remember there being one that produced efficient C and from there you can get to llvm-ir.

Comment: I used it and it works well. . However, in my case, I wanted to use the compile the produced c file with clang to make IR file. However, running IR file, the output is not desirable. Any idea in this particular case?